# play framework conf file inclusion by variable name

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a config file that needs to include a different config file, but the name of the file varies from one environment to another. I'm using environment variables all across the config (e.g. `${?database_server_url}`) and it works perfectly, but when I do `include "${?environment}.conf"` it doesn't work.

Has anyone done it or knows how to do it right?

Thanks!